# Angular returning an empty page, even though all the data is there

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've been building a website with angular for the first time and ran into an issue. Once I click on ' view project ' it should return the data specific to that item. Now if I console.log my js I can see everythign being there. In the console I can also see all of the html being there. So my question is; What could be causing this?

http://robbin-jagt.com/try1/

```
    angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('werkCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.title = "Werk";
    $scope.portfolio_items = [];
    $scope.detail_items = {};
    $scope.beschrijving = "Een verzameling van mijn favoriete werken.";

    var getPortfolioItems = function() {
        $http.get('data/work.json').success(function(data){ 
            $scope.portfolio_items = data;
        });
    }
    getPortfolioItems();

    var getDetailItem = function() {
        var route = $location.path().substring(1).split('/')[1];
        $http.get('data/work.json').success(function(data) {
            for (key in data) {
              if (data[key].slug == route) {
                $scope.detail_items = data[key];
                console.log(data);
              }
            }
        })
    }
    getDetailItem();
  }]);
```

As you can see here I am loading all my data from a json file. I'm looping through the data to find the 'slug' refering to the specific url for the items. This part seems to do it's work since every product is getting an unique slug.

```
<section class="web_wrapper">
<div ng-repeat="item in detail_items">
    <section class="head_image">
        <figure>
            <img ng-src="{{ item.headerimg }}"></img>
            <figcaption>
                <h1>{{ item.title }}</h1>
                <p>{{ item.beschrijvingfoto }}</p>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </section>
    <section class="details">
        <h1>{{ item.name }}</h1>
        <h2>{{ item.date }}</h2>
        <img ng-src="{{item.image}}">
        <div class="text_wrap">
            <p>{{ item.beschrijving }}</p>
            <p>{{ item.beschrijving2 }}</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

This is the detail page where the mentioned above data should be displayed in.

```
 angular
  .module('app', [
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
      })
      .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'templates/about.html',
        controller: 'aboutCtrl'
      })
      .state('werk', {
        url: '/werk',
        templateUrl: 'templates/werk.html',
        controller: 'werkCtrl'
      })
      .state('werkdetail', {
        url: '/werkdetail/:slug',
        templateUrl: 'templates/werkdetail.html',
        controller: 'werkCtrl'
      })
  }])
```

And lastly this is my route. Now I am sorry for not proving a fiddle since i'm not sure how to set one up properly for an angular file. I hope the website linked above will provide you with any other data you need.

```
[
 {  
    "title" : "werk enzo",
    "name" : "product 1",
    "date" : "august 13",
    "image" : "http://placehold.it/400x200",
    "slug" : "product-1",
    "beschrijving" : "blabla",
    "beschrijving2" : "abba abba",
    "headerimg" : "http://placehold.it/1440x400",
    "beschrijvingfoto" : "ding over foto"
},
{   
    "title" : "werk enzo",
    "name" : "product 2",
    "date" : "august 3",
    "image" : "http://placehold.it/400x200",
    "slug" : "product-2",
    "beschrijving" : "blabla",
    "beschrijving2" : "abba abba",
    "headerimg" : "http://placehold.it/1440x400",
    "beschrijvingfoto" : "ding over foto"
},
{   
    "title" : "werk enzo",
    "name" : "product 3",
    "date" : "august 22",
    "image" : "http://placehold.it/400x200",
    "slug" : "product-3",
    "beschrijving" : "blabla",
    "beschrijving2" : "abba abba",
    "headerimg" : "http://placehold.it/1440x400",
    "beschrijvingfoto" : "ding over foto"
},
{   
    "title" : "werk enzo",
    "name" : "product 4",
    "date" : "august 29",
    "image" : "http://placehold.it/400x200",
    "slug" : "product-4",
    "beschrijving" : "blabla",
    "beschrijving2" : "abba abba",
    "headerimg" : "http://placehold.it/1440x400",
    "beschrijvingfoto" : "ding over foto"
}
```

]

This is the Json file I am getting all my data from.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you pass object instead of array to your template:

```
    var getDetailItem = function() {
        var route = $location.path().substring(1).split('/')[1];
        $http.get('data/work.json').success(function(data) {
            for (key in data) {
              if (data[key].slug == route) {
                // data[key] is object
                $scope.detail_items = data[key];

                // you print the whole data array to console but actually passing just one object to $scope.detail_items
                console.log(data);
              }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: I've told my scope i'm passing an object though ( $scope.detail_items = {};) so it isn't expecting an array there. Or is that still a problem?

Comment: But your template is expecting an array of objects: <div ng-repeat="item in detail_items">

Comment: I'm not familiar with passing objects into a repeat, would it be something like ({ item in detail_items}) ?

Comment: If you are passing object like $scope.item = {title: "123"} to a template, you can access it's properties in your template like {{ item.title }}. If you pass a collection (array of objects) like $scope.items = [{title: "123"}, {title: "234"}] then you iterate over them by using ng-repeat="item in items" and access each item's properties like {{ item.title }}

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that...

```
for (key in data) {}
```

...is not the best way to iterate over an array?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

If you expect an array, use

```
for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {}
```

instead.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I've tried your solutions, sadly it didn't change anything. Thank you anyway!

Comment: yes, I know, it was only an improvement suggested.

As you want to display an individual item (product selected by unique slug) you must remove the ng-repeat in the detail "view" and change the bindings from "item.xxx" to "detail_items.xxx" (and rename  "detail_items" to "detail_item" later as the name is misleading).